# Search for a specific text in a spreadsheet and sum up all these cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that looks like:

```
------------------
| A | B | C  | D  |
------------------
| 1 | 5 |bla |bla1| 
------------------
| 2 |10 |bla2|bla2| 
------------------
| 3 |10 |bla2|bla1| 
------------------
| 4 | 5 |bla |bla2|
------------------
```

I want to sum up all cells in column `B` where the string `bla2` is in column `D` and only in `D` and not in `C`. (So the sum should be `15`.)

How would you do that in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIF(D:D,"bla2",B:B)
```

should work (same as Excel).